# DateTime.UtcNow and DateTime.Now returned wrong time

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I am using `DateTime.UtcNow` and `DateTime.Now` in c# 
but both of them return wrong hour and minutes.

My correct time is 23:04 and its return 20:34 or something like that

I put this code before the DateTime function:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
```

but the same...

what can i do ?

Comment: since it's highly improbable that these a trillion times tested properties have such an obvious bug, can you please check your machine''s time again and post the code you use to display the values as strings?

Comment: ...or something like that

Comment: You do not provide much info. A difference of 2:30 corresponds to the time zone distance between Israel (where you might be according to your profile here?) and Afghanistan. Do you have any reason to think that the regional settings or physical location of the machine is related to Afghanistan?

Comment: You try to clear cache on the `CultureInfo`, but `CultureInfo` holds a language and sometimes a country. That is not enough to give time zone since some countries span more than one time zone. You must search the info elsewhere. What does `TimeZoneInfo.Local.ToString()` return? As others asked, how do you format your `DateTime`? What does `DateTime.Now.ToString("o")` give? With `"o"` you will see a time zone hint (related to `TimeZoneInfo.Local`) when the `DateTime` instance has `.Kind` equal to `Local`. Supply more information to us.

Comment: do you know the difference of `DateTime.UtcNow` and `DateTime.Now` in the first place? @kfir

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to show the value of your datetime.

Comment: @Plutonix Relative time.

Comment: Well I am experiencing that as well, also from Israel but with Python.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your computer's  Time and Time Zone setup. You have one of two options:

1) Code:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("DateTime.Now: ", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay));
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("DateTime.UtcNow: ", DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay));
Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

string tziString = TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id;

Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(tziString, ": ", 
    TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tziString)).TimeOfDay));

Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("UTC Offset: ", TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTimeOffset.Now)));
```

Result:

[image: Code Result]

2) Right Click on the date and time in the right hand side of the task bar and click "Adjust date/time":

[image: Adjust Date Time]

You would have to go through option 2 to change it if the Time Zone settings are incorrect, so that would be the option that I start would with.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear what is your time zone ? for Pacfic standard time zone use you could change the string name accordng to your requirement and also PS recheck your System time.

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow,
  TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"));
```